# sizeof(struct)... gives wrong result , VS 2010

Tags: c++, structure, sizeof

```
struct test{
    int year;
    char text;
    double num;
};

int main ()
{

 test t;
 cout<<sizeof(t);
  return 0;
}
```

The result is 16, while I was expecting 13. Since sizeof(char) is 1. What am I missing here?

Comment: `double` will be stored mem aligned (at word size).

Comment: If the compiler gives an answer that is not what you are expecting, it is usually not the compiler that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

C++ may add padding between members. The struct might therefore be larger than the added size of its members.